# Generating a client from WSDL and java version error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies, executable-jar

I have the task to built a java JAR that works fine with JAVA 6. The functionality is not complex, it just needs to call a SOAP WS (the WSDL was provided to me) and then exit with 0 or -1 wether the WS return ok or not ok. Seems easy.

I'm using Eclipse IDE, so I was able to generate the client from the WSDL and the schema provided and I only had to built the parameter object from the arguments the JAR receives and do some validations on dates, quantities and stuff like that. I'm using Maven to manage the dependencies because at first, the auto generated client didn't work well and it kept throwing error as "class not found" or "class not def", so I added the following dependencies in order to solve all of these errors:

```
<dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.1</version>
          <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.informix</groupId>
            <artifactId>ifxjdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.informix</groupId>
            <artifactId>ifxjdbcx</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I tested it on my local machine and it worked well, from Eclipse console and from my Windows CMD console...

The thing is this JAR is part of a bigger process, so my workmates are going to execute it on another machine. When I export it and they try to execute it throws a version error on some classes like ProviderImpl (which is a class I didn't create of course, it's some dependency):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sun/xml/ws/spi/ProviderImpl : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:648)
       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:272)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:68)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:207)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:201)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:200)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:325)
       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:296)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:270)
       at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.safeLoadClass(FactoryFinder.java:170)
       at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:50)
       at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:110)
       at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:102)
       at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:76)
       at com.mvc.model.services.webservices.proposals.ProposalsService_Service.<init>(ProposalsService_Service.java:39)
       at mainpackage.MainClass.setEndpoint(MainClass.java:69)
       at mainpackage.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:44)
```

This how I deduced that on my local environment, my jar was using the correct java version for its dependencies automatically (I have a couple of jdks installed and default one is newer than Java 6), but the production environment my team is on only have Java 6.

So my question is: how can I solve this? Why did the generate client from Eclipse used this class even if I have the build path of the project configured to Java 6?

I already tried using older versions, but it's impossible for the rt one because there are no Java 6 version or I couldn't find it. I also tried specifying the maven compiler version in the pom.xml, but it didn't do nothing for me. So i'm out of options, because they can't change the Java version of that environment.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: You can get JDK 6 from the archive https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-java-archive-javase6-downloads.html - and maybe an older version of eclipse as well (try eclipse kepler) - if oracle's JDK is not an option, you can try OpenJDK 6 as well https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk6/

Comment: major version 52 is for Java 8. I think you built the project using java 8 and wanted to run it using java 6 that's why this exception is thrown. what is your Maven version? according to Maven Documentation the last version that works with Java 1.6 is 3.2.5

Comment: My Maven version 3.2.1 so I think that's okay. I probably built it with Java 8 or latest, but I don't get why Eclipse did that, because Java 6 it's on the project's build path so when I generated the WS client, it should have used...well, java 6 stuff and that's it. I'm confussed. Thank you!